# Requiring NumericQ in Pure Function

Tags: function-construction, interpolation, pure-function

Potential duplicate, but doesn't seem to solve my problem:
[Using patterns in pure functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/using-patterns-in-pure-functions)

I have a function that returns an `InterpolatingFunction`, and it works exactly the way I needed for passing to `NIntegrate` etc.: if I pass on a symbolic argument, the function returns itself; if the argument is numeric, it evaluates and gives a number.

```
func := Module[{...}, ... (y /. First@NDSolve[{y[1] == 1, y'[x] == x}, y, {x, -1, 1}])]
func[x] (* gives InterpolatingFunction[(-1. 1.),<>](x) *)
func[0.5] (* gives 0.625 *)
```

I need a slightly modified behavior: the returned function should return 0 if outside the range instead of attempting to interpolate. Seems easy enough:

```
func := Module[{interpolation,...}, ...
        interpolation = (y /. First@NDSolve[{y[1] == 1, y'[x] == x}, y, {x, -1, 1}]);
        Function[x,If[Not@IntervalMemberQ[Interval[interpolation[[1, 1]]], x], 0, 
                interpolation[x]]]]
func[0.5] (* gives 0.625 *) 
func[2] (* gives 0 since it's outside the interpolation interval *)
func[x] (* gives 0!! *)
```

How can one mimic the behavior of `InterpolatingFunction` such that `func[x]` for non-numeric `x` gives something like `Function[<>](x)` instead?

Comment: From the documentation of [Function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html): "Function][params, body, {attr_1, attr_2, ...}] represents a pure function that is to be treated as having attributes attr_i for the purpose of evaluation".

Answer (score 3):

This is not neat at all but it gives the bahaviour you need:

```
ClearAll[func];
func := Module[{interpolation},
  interpolation = (y /. First@NDSolve[{y[1] == 1, y'[x] == x}, y, {x, -1, 1}]);
  Function[x,
    Which[
      ! NumericQ[x], interpolation[x], 
      TrueQ[LessEqual[#, x, #2] & @@ interpolation[[1, 1]]], interpolation[x],
      True, 0]]]

func[0.5] 
func[2] 
func[x]
```

> ```
> 0.625
> 0
> InterpolatingFunction[{{-1.,1.}},<>][x]
> ```