# Custom operators; custom pattern matching with pure functions

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, operators, custom-notation

What I'm trying to achieve in *Mathematica* is the creation of a binary operator whose operands are both pure functions over the natural numbers. The result of the operator should be another pure function over the natural numbers.

To demonstrate concretely what I want, suppose I have the following functions defined:

```
f[n_Natural]:=2*n;
g[n_Natural]:=n-1;
```

(There is no Head called "Natural" so the above pattern matching won't work. But I want *f* and *g* to accept only natural numbers. This is **problem No. 1** [SOLVED])

I then want a binary operator defined like so:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
CombinedFunction[f_NaturalFunction,g_NaturalFunction]:={#}/.{{x_Natural}:>f[#]+g[#]}}&;
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[CirclePlus]"], CombinedFunction];
```

Operating $f$ $\oplus$ $g$ yields a pure function $h$ that only takes a natural number as an argument. I have found a way of enforcing the domain of $h$ thanks to [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/using-patterns-in-pure-functions), but I want to extend this to ensure that $\oplus$ itself is only defined for unary functions over the natural numbers. Seeing as there's no Head like 'NaturalFunction', I don't know how to do this. This is **problem No. 2**.

As an additional issue, the operator (which currently yields a function defined over the integers) currently gives an unsimplified output:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
CombinedFunction[f_, g_] := {#} /. {{x_Integer} :> f[x] + g[x]} &;
AddInputAlias["4" -> ParsedBoxWrapper["\[CirclePlus]"]];
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[CirclePlus]"], CombinedFunction];

f=1&;
g=#&;
h=f\[CirclePlus]g
```

> ```
> {#1} /. {{x$_Integer} :> (1 &)[x$] \[LeftRightArrow] (#1 &)[x$]} &
> ```

I would have expected the output to be:

> ```
> (1+#)&
> ```

I'm unsure of the inner workings of what I've written so I don't know how to obtain a simplified result. I can now apply $h$ to an integer and it operates as expected. However:

```
h[3.5]
```

> ```
> {3.5}
> ```

I want instead *Mathematica* to behave as if the function was simply undefined for anything but an integer, just as it would do if I defined $h$ like so:

```
Clear[h]; h[x_Integer]:=x+1;
h[3.5]
```

> ```
> h[3.5]
> ```

Comment: `f[n_Integer /; Positive[n]] := 2*n;
g[n_Integer /; Positive[n]] := n - 1;` (note *Natural* has a definition where 0 is included, if that's what you need, change condition...

Comment: Cheers, that solves the first problem!

Comment: Have a look at `DownValues` - if the functions involved are just your definitions and you use a consistent format for the "naturals" constraint (and /or also wrap any "foreign" function with a definition of your making with the constraint) you can parse the pattern to see if constraint is present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without giving this much thought you might proceed as follows:

```
naturalQ = IntegerQ[#] && Positive[#] &;
```

You can then define:

```
fn[n_?naturalQ] := 2*n;

fn /@ {-1, 0, 1}
```

> ```
> {fn[-1], fn[0], 2}
> ```

For the second problem you might make use of [SubValues syntax](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8003/121):

```
SetAttributes[nFun, HoldAll]

nFun[p_, body_][arg_?naturalQ] := With[{p = arg}, body]
```

Now:

```
nFun[x, x^2][8]
nFun[x, 2 x][8]
nFun[x, x+5][8]
```

> ```
> 64
> 16
> 13
> ```

You can define `CirclePlus` directly since it is an operator.  You don't need the Notation package.  (You can enter the `\[CirclePlus]` character with <kbd>Esc</kbd>`c+`<kbd>Esc</kbd>.)  Again using SubValues syntax:

```
CirclePlus[f_nFun, g_nFun][arg_?naturalQ] := f[arg] + g[arg]
```

Now:

```
f = nFun[x, x];
g = nFun[x, 1];
h = f \[CirclePlus] g
h[7]
```

> ```
> 8
> ```

This doesn't produce a `Function` object but perhaps it is sufficient.  If it is not acceptable please explain how and why and I shall try again.

---

Anticipating a possible request, and also offering a variant, here is a method that makes use of `Slot` notation and yields partial evaluation:

```
ClearAll[nFun, CirclePlus]

SetAttributes[nFun, HoldFirst]
nFun[body_][arg__?naturalQ] := body &[arg]

CirclePlus[nFun[b1_], nFun[b2_]] := nFun[b1 + b2]
```

Now:

```
f = nFun[#];
g = nFun[1];

h = f\[CirclePlus]g
h[7]
```

> ```
> nFun[#1 + 1]
>
> 8
> ```

For complete evaluation of the body you can use `nFun @@ {b1 + b2}` for the RHS of the second definition.

Comment: This contains a lot of useful information for me, thank you. I'll define the CirclePlus directly and use the boolean *_?* from now on. However, I still desire that f \[CirclePlus] g return a pure function. The idea is to produce an abelian group of functions of natural numbers that is closed under addition. So it is essential that adding f and g return another function which you wouldn't know had come from an operation.

Comment: I look forward to your expansion of this (I *know* it's coming... ;-} ). Have not thought it out much, but my gut feeling is part of this (limiting functions sent to circle-plus to those with domain naturals) is an interesting problem if they include functions not defined by the user. Other than wrapping such things in an appropriate user-defined skeleton, is there a way to interrogate "foreign" functions (e.g., what if `Prime` were one of the functions - how might one tell its domain is the naturals?). +1, if only to prod...

Comment: @Myridium Please see my update made moments before your comment.

Comment: @rasher I don't have the strength to dig into this to that level right now.  I couldn't sleep so here I am, but I'm still tired.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=metwE-QpgAY

Comment: @rasher LOL! :-D  If only it were that easy -- but preferably without strangulation.

Comment: Ah, this is good! A kind of 'nFun' class of functions which enforce that their argument be natural numbers. I suppose then that I could wrap any function at all with *nFun[ ... ]* to to make it conform to this restriction! 

One note: I've made a tweak and added an evaluate: *nFun[Evaluate[b1+b2]]* 
so that nFun[#]$\oplus$nFun[2#] = nFun[3#] for instance. This shouldn't cause problems, should it?

Comment: @Myridium Thanks for the Accept.  I'll try to review this tomorrow when I'm more awake and hopefully thinking better, if I have time.  Your `Evaluate` expression should do the same this as `nFun @@ {b1 + b2}` which I mentioned at the bottom of my present answer.  It shouldn't cause problems unless there are operations within the `body` expressions that behave incorrectly with symbolic input.  There remains issues and cases to address; for example you may want `f \[CirclePlus] g \[CirclePlus] h` to work properly; I will need to change the definition for that.

Comment: Extending it in this way would certainly be appreciated. And right you are about the @@; I had missed that.

Comment: Adding attributes "Flat" and "Orderless" to *CirclePlus* has done the trick to make $\oplus$ automatically associative. Only thing left to do perhaps is have the operator $\oplus$ take precedence over argument to *nFun[ ... ]*. i.e. $f \oplus g \oplus h[5]=(f \oplus g \oplus h)[5]$ Not sure if that's possible though.

Comment: @Myridium for what it's worth you could instead use a definition like `CirclePlus[fns : nFun[_] ..] := Thread[+fns, nFun]` or for complete evaluation `:= nFun @@ {(+fns)[[All, 1]]}`.  Regarding binding power I don't think you should change it as such things are standardized (see [(30430)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30430)); I'm not saying it's impossible, at least from the Notebook interface, but I don't recommend messing with it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard i find gems when i read your answers ! +1