# Algebraic expressions on pure functions

Tags: evaluation, symbolic, pure-function

I would like to know how to perform algebraic operations with pure functions.

**Simple version:**

Here's a silly toy model: I want to transform the algebraic expression
  Sin*Cos
into the function evaluated at r, that is,
  Sin[r]*Cos[r].
But I could not find any way to use Apply or Evaluate to do this. In other words, I would like to make Mathematica understand that something like this is true:

```
(Sin*Cos)[r_] := Sin[r_]*Cos[r_]
```

and analogously for all other possible pure functions.
I realize that this means I need to convert

```
(Sin[#] &) Cos[#] &
```

into the version without the first '&', so that the whole expression defines only one pure function:

```
(Sin[#]) Cos[#] &[r]
```

---

**Full version:**

I have more elaborate algebraic expressions with two symbols 'Fm' and 'Fp', which I think as representing pure functions that will be defined later. These expressions involve derivatives, squares, etc., of these functions, for instance:

```
4 Fm Derivative[1][Fm]
```

or

```
1/4 Fp (2 Fp - Fp^3/Fm^2 + 4 Fm Derivative[1][Fm] Derivative[1][Fp])
```

I then want to simplify these expressions when I choose explicit pure functions, such as:

```
Fm = Sin[#] &;
Fp = Sin[#] Cos[#] &;
```

But when I declare these pure functions as above and then re-evaluate the expressions, I get:

```
4 (Cos[#1] &) (Sin[#1] &)
1/4 (Sin[#1] Cos[#1] &) (2 (Sin[#1] Cos[#1] &) - (Sin[#1] Cos[#1] &)^3/(Sin[#1] &)^2 + 4 (Cos[#1] &) (Sin[#1] &) (Cos[#1]^2 - Sin[#1]^2 &))
```

and instead I would like to get

```
4 Cos[#1] Sin[#1] &
1/4 (Sin[#1] Cos[#1]) (2 (Sin[#1] Cos[#1]) - (Sin[#1] Cos[#1])^3/(Sin[#1])^2 + 4 (Cos[#1]) (Sin[#1]) (Cos[#1]^2 - Sin[#1]^2)) &
```

Again, the solution to this is essentially erasing the '&'s systematically (except the very last one); but I don't know how to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Related: [(48786)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48786)

Answer (score 4):

There may be a better way to do this, but perhaps

```
4 Fm Derivative[1][Fm] /. Function[b_] :> b // Evaluate // Function
```

> 4 Cos[#1] Sin[#1]&

```
1/4 Fp (2 Fp - Fp^3/Fm^2 + 
  4 Fm Derivative[1][Fm] Derivative[1][Fp]) /. Function[b_] :> b // Evaluate // Function
```

> 1/4 Cos[#1] Sin[#1] (2 Cos[#1] Sin[#1]-Cos[#1]^3 Sin[#1]+4 Cos[#1] Sin[#1] (Cos[#1]^2-Sin[#1]^2))&

Comment: (+1) or `foo = Composition[Function, Evaluate, # /. Function -> Identity &]` and `foo[expr]`

Comment: @kguler Nice use of `Identity` -- that's definitely going in my bag of tricks.

Comment: In this case `Function -> Identity` works just as well.

Comment: Sorry, Sequence, not Identity.

Answer (score 2):

Merely my own variation of the existing answer by mfvonh:

```
expr = 1/4 Fp (2 Fp - Fp^3/Fm^2 + 4 Fm Derivative[1][Fm] Derivative[1][Fp]);

Fm = Sin[#] &;
Fp = Sin[#] Cos[#] &;

FullSimplify[expr /. (x_ &) :> x]
Function @@ {%}
```

> ```
> 1/32 (3 + 7 Cos[2 #1]) Sin[2 #1]^2
>
> 1/32 (3 + 7 Cos[2 #1]) Sin[2 #1]^2 &
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Postfix-Definition

```
Clear@"`*"

Sin*Cos // f[r_] := Sin[r]*Cos[r]

Sin*Cos // f[Pi/7]

(* out *)
Cos[Pi/7] Sin[Pi/7]
```

Prefix-Definition

```
Clear@"`*"
g[r_][Sin*Cos] := Sin[r]*Cos[r]

g[Pi/11][Sin*Cos]

(*out*)
Cos[Pi/11] Sin[Pi/11]
```

Just 1 letter more to type

Comment: (+1) or `h[r_, ff_] := Through@ ff @ r; h[r, Sin Cos]`

Comment: Just curious, why are you making the postfix/prefix distinction?

Comment: I first wrote the postfix-definition, then I thought readers are more familiar with prefix-notation. In a code text the notations have different precedences.

Answer (score 1):

Another replacement version:

```
expr /. (x_ &) :> x /. x_ :> (x &)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just a simple replacement rule?

```
mergeF[expr_] := expr /. {((Cos[#1] &) (Sin[#1] &)) :> (Sin[#] Cos[#] &)}

mergeF[Fm Derivative[1][Fm]]
(* Sin[#1] Cos[#1] & *)

mergeF[1/4 Fp (2 Fp - Fp^3/Fm^2 + 4 Fm Derivative[1][Fm] Derivative[1][Fp])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]