# What is primary, function computation or function application?

Tags: functions, evaluation

What is the order of computations here?

```
 g[x_]:=x^2;
 f[x_]:=Sqrt[g[x]];
 Map[f, Range[100]]
```

Does this code first gets $f(x)=x$ and then gives its values or for every $n$ it calculates $n^2$ and then its square root?

In the latter case, how can I first get $f(x)=x$?

Comment: `Refine[Sqrt[x^2], x \[Element] Reals]
(*Abs[x]*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If I understand your meaning there is no "function computation" in *Mathematica*, except in some internal routines.  The code is not compiled and it is not optimized in the manner you inquire about.  Instead the operations are performed in a far more direct and literal fashion.  Due to the potential complexity of *Mathematica* functions it frequently would not make sense to attempt to pre-evaluate them in this way.  When and if you want this kind of "function computation" you have to implement in manually.  `WReach` already gave you an example of this.  Here is of my own: [Custom operators; custom pattern matching with pure functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48786/custom-operators-custom-pattern-matching-with-pure-functions/48789#48789).
2. Since `f` does not evaluate to anything but itself it is literally mapped onto the list before any further evaluation takes place.  See [Scan vs. Map vs. Apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/121) for my own description of this.
3. While not as efficient as "function computation" would be in this case it is worth noting that since both your operations are natively [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) it is more efficient to avoid `Map` and apply them directly, e.g. `f @ Range[100]`.  See case #5 in [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121).

Answer (score 13):

We can use some of *Mathematica's* built-in tracing facilities to help us answer this question.

Let's start by ensuring that the symbols we are about to use carry no extraneous definitions:

```
ClearAll[f, g, x]
```

Now, we'll establish the definitions from the question:

```
g[x_] := x^2
f[x_] := Sqrt[g[x]]
```

We can turn on selective tracing of some functions to see what is going on:

```
On[f, g, Sqrt]
```

Now, let's evaluate `f` for several values (here only 3 instead of 100 to keep the output manageable):

```
Map[f, Range[3]]
```

[image: trace output]

This shows us that `f` and `g` are being evaluated from first principles for each value in the range.

Should we wish to evaluate `f[x]` only once, applying the resultant expression to each value, then we must do something like this:

```
Map[Function[{x}, Evaluate@f[x]],  Range[3]]
```

[image: trace output]

The expression defines an anonymous function of *x*, whose body is the result of evaluating `f[x]`.  It is very important that `x` has no value at this point -- that is why we cleared it at the beginning.  Having done that, we can now see that `f` and `g` were only evaluated for `x` instead of for every range value.

Incidentally, observe that `f[x]` ultimately evaluates to `Sqrt[x^2]` rather than `x` since *Mathematica* does not assume that `x` can only be a positive real number.

The syntax used in the preceding example can be abbreviated if we use so-called "slot" notation (`#`):

```
Map[Evaluate@f[#] &,  Range[3]]
```

[image: trace output]

Again, we can see that `f` and `g` are not evaluated for each range element.  The slot reference `#1` has taken the place of the named variable `x` from the previous example.

Once we have completed our analysis, and are tired of seeing all those trace messages, we can turn off tracing like this:

```
Off[]
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that you are using `:=`, also known by its `FullForm` name `SetDelayed`, to define your functions. According to the Documentation Center page for `:=`:

> `lhs := rhs` assigns `rhs` to be the delayed value of `lhs`. `rhs` is maintained in an unevaluated form. When `lhs` appears, it is replaced by `rhs`, evaluated afresh each time.

This means that `Sqrt[g[x]]` is maintained in an unevaluated form, meaning that the latter case of your first question is how the calculation works internally; in other words, it does *not* conclude $f(x)=x$. More importantly, *it doesn't even look at* `Sqrt[g[x]]`, except to store it as a definition.

As an additional example, consider the following:

```
h[x_] := Pause[1];
```

The definition proceeds instantly, which indicates that Mathematica doesn't even touch the definition. However, executing `h[x]` takes one second.

For your second question, in general it is not possible to conclude $\sqrt{x^2}=x$, unless $x$ is real and nonnegative. You can force it to use such an assumption as follows:

```
Refine[f[x], x > 0]
(*x*)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the first part of my question is clear for me. Now, what should I do if I want first to calculate $g$ and then apply it to $1,\ldots,100$? The only way I know so far is to divide computations into two sessions: the first session is for calculation of $g$ and the second one if for its application.

Comment: @8k14: What does "calculate $g$" mean? $g(x)=x^2$, so there is no simplification that can be done. Does `g /@ Range[100]` not do what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the calculation of $f$.

Comment: It seems that the model code I put in my question is not good. Actually $f$ is a simple function, say a polynomial, with high computational complexity. I need to evaluate $f$ at many points that's why I want to calculate it before its application.

Comment: @8k14: I'm still not totally sure what you're trying to do, but my best guess is that you want to simplify $f(x)$ first, and then substitute in various values of $x$. In that case, you could do `f[x_] := Evaluate[(*Insert code*)]` in the case that $f$ is simple enough that automatic simplification occurs, or alternately `f[x_] := Evaluate[Simplify[(*Insert code*)]]` in the case that more firepower is needed. By adding an `Evaluate` wrapper, the code inside is forcibly evaluated first, and then the resulting expression is used.

Comment: Sorry for my complex explanations, your guess is right and your answer is what I really need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Like k_v also proposed `Refine` can be used.

```
ClearAll[f, g, h];
g[x_] := x^2;
f[x_] := Sqrt[g[x]];
h[x_] = Block[{x}, Refine[f[x], x > 0]];
Trace@Map[h, Range[100]]
```

`h[x]===x` returns `True`

Answer (score 3):

You can answer your question by using the built-in function [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trace.html).

```
g[x_] := x^2
f[x_] := Sqrt[g[x]]
Trace[Map[f, Range[3]]]
```

> ```
> {
>  {Range[3], {1, 2, 3}},
>  f /@ {1, 2, 3},  {f[1], f[2], f[3]},
>  {f[1], Sqrt[g[1]], {g[1], 1^2, 1}, Sqrt[1], 1},
>  {f[2], Sqrt[g[2]], {g[2], 2^2, 4}, Sqrt[4], 2},
>  {f[3], Sqrt[g[3]], {g[3], 3^2, 9}, Sqrt[9], 3},
>  {1, 2, 3}
> }
> ```

From the output of `Trace` you can see that things happen as follows:

1. `Range[3]` is replaced by `{1, 2, 3}`
2. Map[f, {1, 2, 3}] is evaluated giving `{f[1], f[2], f[3]}`
3. `f[1]` is replaced by `Sqrt[g[1]]`
4. `g[1]` is replaced by 1^1 which is replaced by 1
5. Sqrt[g[1]] is replaced by `Sqrt[1]`,  which is replaced by 1
6. Now the `f[2]` and the `f[3]` argument of `{f[1], f[2], f[3]}` are processed in the same manner as `f[1]`.
7. The evaluator has now transformed `Map[f, Range[3]]` into `{1, 2, 3}`. No further transformation is possible, so evaluation ends, returning `{1, 2, 3}`.